# how to custom image field in django

Tags: html, django

I have a form that has an imageField :

Models:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    avatar_image = models.ImageField(default=..., upload_to=...,)
```

Forms:

```py
class Avatar(forms.Form):
    avatar_image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput,required=False)

    class Meta:
       model = Image
       fields = ['avatar_image']
```

When I use this form in a html template I get this result:

[image: form field]

But I want to have something like this:

[image: field 2]

How can I do this ?

Comment: u have to create custom html, css, and javascript/jquery

Comment: You're using the default widget: `widget=forms.FileInput`. Design your own widget for selecting an image.